# Apostrophe's rules in plural

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

Are we allowed to use (') to express possession  or is it incorrect usage?

For example

> My parents's wealth is precious to me<

Comment: Thanks providing the link! truth is that I've never seen that or thought that it would be duplicate!

Comment: Putting "Apostrophe's rules in plural" into the search-box above gives 80 hits, including (very early on) the one I mention.